# Регулярные выражения, выборка подстроки

Tags: javascript, php, html

Помогите написать регулярное выражения для поиска подстроки.
Есть строка в виде массива $str = ["2020-8-31","2020-8-24"], мне надо вытащить только цифры(даты).

И ещё сразу вопрос, а есть такая команда, чтобы вот эту запись в виде массива из строки преобразовать в массив?

Спасибо.

Comment: Гугли формат данных __json__, регулярные выражения здесь не нужны.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам. Пишу ответ, может кому пригодится.

```
$str = ["2020-8-31","2020-8-24"]
```

/неважно что идёт до и после цифр/[^кроме цифр] заменить на пробел

```
$str= preg_replace('/[^0-9-]/', ' ', $str);
```